# Netdisco FileNotFoundError after converted to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, file-not-found

Working on a python 3.7 script that uses netdisco (https://github.com/home-assistant/netdisco) to scan the local network for IOT devices. Everything works fine when running the program via python. However, after converting the script to an executable on Windows 10 the program fails when attempting to read a file from the User/appData/temp/ folder. The netdisco script throws a FileNotFoundError on line 52 of discovery.py(https://github.com/home-assistant/netdisco/blob/master/netdisco/discovery.py) in the netdisco project.
The file that netdisco is attempting to read does not exist so I think that something else is failing to create it but I haven't found a reference to any file creation in netdisco.

Other information:
Ran the .exe as an administrator and regular user
Pyinstaller builds the .exe from the original script with no problems
This is on Windows 10 from start to finish.
The error occurs when NetworkDiscovery.scan() is called

Comment: What do you mean/use when you write that you are converting it to a Windows 10 executable.

Comment: Using pyinstaller to build the .py file into a windows 10 executable. @mrangry777

Answer (score 0):

Netdisco defines devices it can scan for in .py files that aren't flagged as a dependency so pyinstaller doesn't add package it during the conversion. The solution I found is to edit the .spec file that pyinstaller uses to add "('path/to/netdisco/discoverables/*', 'netdisco/discoverables')"